# Oraclize : Calling more than one API independently

Tags: solidity, ethereumjs, oracles

There are 2 API 's which has to be called in different time delays recursively.
For example : API_1 = 20 mins delay and API_2 = 24 hr delay.

How can we call the above 2 API's independently based on their own delays using same oraclize instance?

Platform : Privatenet

Comment: Thank you, but I want to execute the above two api's together(on delays) in contract recursively without the help of js.